# Is there a way to save (and then reuse) filters created via the REST API in RALLY

Tags: rally

I need to create a number of filters to select specific objects in Rally. I 'really' want to do that in the UI, and then just reference them in my application. (this lets others tune the results, while my app just gets the counts of items)..

I don't see a way to save the queryFilter by name and then find it again, or find filters created thru the UI

Comment: I see there are 'views' which look like a 'filter' over particular types and attributes.   one can save the view...  can I find a list of views in a rest api application, and then execute one of them? I only want counts of objects matching the view filter, not the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to do this.  The custom views on pages like User Story or the saved views on pages like Backlog are internal to the application and are not really exposed via WSAPI.

There's no reason you couldn't store a json blob describing your view in the value of a Preference object though.  That's basically what the saved views on the Backlog page does...

Comment: thanks.. but saving the application created filter def doesn't really help at all. the app still has to do the work.. I can['t give the responsibility to someone to create and maintain the filters, and the app just use them.

Comment: also, I'm not sure what value the QueryFilter.toString() method provides.. sure would be nice to be able to recreate a Queryfilter FROM the String representation.

Comment: you can do that: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Filter-static-method-fromQueryString